# Insert into rows based on percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with employees. I need to populate the table with data based on 10 values from another table which contains 10 rows with columns ID and a name. I have to divide the employees in almost equal groups and add the IDs from the other table.

For example, 10% of employees should have first ID from the other table, other 10% of employees should have second ID from the same table etc.

Here is an example table of the employees

```
EmployeeID | Name | LevelID
----------------
 1  | Name 1 | NULL
 2  | Name 2 | NULL
 3  | Name 3 | NULL
...
 998  | Name 998 | NULL
 999  | Name 999 | NULL
 1000  | Name 1000 | NULL
```

Here is an example table of levels

```
LevelID | Level
----------------
 1  | Level 1
 2  | Level 2
 3  | Level 3
...
 8 | Level 8
 9 | Level 9
 10 | Level 10
```

I want my employee table to be updated like this:

```
EmployeeID | Name | LevelID
----------------
 1  | Name 1 | 1
 2  | Name 2 | 1
...
 100  | Name 100 | 1
 101  | Name 101 | 2
...
 300  | Name 300 | 3
 301  | Name 301 | 4
 302  | Name 302 | 4
...
 998  | Name 998 | 10
 999  | Name 999 | 10
 1000  | Name 1000 | 10
```

How can I achieve this in a query from SQL Server.

Kindly help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I have updated the question with an example

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the values using window functions:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from (select t1.*, ntile(10) over (order by (select null)) as tile
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t2.seqnum = t1.tile;
```

If you want to do this as an `update`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t1.*, ntile(10) over (order by (select null)) as tile
      from table1 t1
     )
update toupdate
    set . . . 
    from toupdate join
         (select t2.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
          from table2 t2
         ) t2
         on t2.seqnum = toupdate.tile;
```